# Only cold water in new shower installation

Tags: shower, hot-water

Converted a separate tub and shower into one large shower. Intake lines were moved from the center wall which separated the tub and shower to a back wall. Put in new mixing valve and am only getting cold. Switched out for another new mixing valve but still getting only cold. The sink and other upstairs all have hot. Most of the work has been done by myself, except for I had a plumber cap off the original intake lines to the tub which was back to back with the original shower, and also move the vent from that location to the back wall.

1. Is it possible that he mistakenly left us with 2 cold supply lines?
2. Or is there another explanation? (please i hope so...)
3. And is there a way to trace the pex lines to the source in the basement? Shower is now all enclosed with tiling...

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: First thing I'd do is call the plumber, who might suddenly remember a mistake and offer to come repair it.  If that leads nowhere, **what's behind the shower valve?**  Any chance there's a closet or something where you don't mind opening up the opposite side of the wall containing the mixing valve?

Comment: Thanks. I'm waiting on his return call. There is a closet behind and we could open the wall to get to the valve from there.